# Toolbar custom themes and styles

Tags: android, android-styles, android-toolbar

I'm currently using toolbar from appCompat v22.2.0 and so far I use the classic themes

```
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
```

But that's too limited so here's what I want to do.

1. Change the color of Title (if possible size and format e.g bold, italic etc)
2. Change the color of Subtitle (if possible size and format e.g bold, italic etc)
3. Change the color of the 3-dotted overflow menu-icon
4. Change text color of the actual popup menu items
5. Change background color of the actual popup menu items

EDIT: It's ok if you can answer only parts of my questions. Whatever I get is good

Comment: For items 1 and 2 see this [recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31028556/how-to-customize-the-action-bar-subtitle-font/31029625#31029625)

Comment: thanks that works for me as far as the size is concerned

Comment: If would guess there are style attributes for items 3,4,5 that can be overridden.  The challenge is digging through the multiple layers of framework style definitions to find them.  I've never found them documented anywhere.